# Dejar fijo, sin scroll un menu lateral mobile css

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, responsive

mi problema consiste en que, al usar mi pagina en una resolucion mobile, abro el menu, y no se me queda fijo, es decir si hago scroll, me lleva hacia abajo de la pagina, cuando lo que busco es lo contrario.
Además, uso un fondo transparente en el menu y si hago scroll, de fondo se ve que sigo bajando.
Ya intente con el overflow y no logre solucionarlo.
Dejo el codigo:

```
<nav class="menu">
<div class="container-menu">
    <div class="logo">
        <a href="index.php">
            <img src="../images/logo-sheltr.png">SHELTR
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="icon-menu">
        <a href="#" id="btn-menu" class="btn-menu" >
            <span class="fa fa-bars"></span>        
        </a>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="menu-links">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php">INICIO</a></li>
        <li><a href="conceptos.php">CONCEPTOS</a></li>
        <li><a href="se-parte.php">SÉ PARTE</a></li>
        <li><a href="inverti.php">INVERTÍ</a></li>
        <li><a href="prueba-piloto.php">PRUEBA PILOTO</a></li>
        <li><a href="contacto.php">CONTACTO</a></li>
    </ul>


</div>
```

y el css:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/*MENU*/
header{
    font-family: helvetica;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
.menu-links ul{
    height: 40px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

/*MEDIQUERIES TABLET*/
@media screen and (max-width: 850px){
    .container-menu{
        height: 60px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        width: 80%;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
    .menu-links{
        position: fixed;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100%;
        top: 60px;
        left: -100%;
        transition: .5s;
    }
    .menu-links ul{
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        height: auto;
    }
}
```

Tambien pense en deshabilitar el scroll con jquery o js, en cada evento que se abre el menu.
Gracias de antemano. Saludos.

Comment: intentaste ponerle al `body` `overflow:hidden` ?

Comment: Funciona, pero no me permite hacer scroll a nada, me queda la pagina estatica.

Comment: Intenta con `z-index: 10000;`

Comment: Tampoco funciona. Lo que hice, fue en el archivo de javascript donde abro o cierro el menu, cuando lo abro, le doy al body overflow:hidden, y cuando lo cierro, le doy visible. Y ahi si funciona. '
   var body = document.querySelector("body");
   $('body').css({'overflow':'hidden'});'
Gracias igualmente! Me sirvió